# Mover botones hasta abajo - CSS

Tags: css

No logro mover estos botones a la posicion deseada.
Como verán en la imagen más abajo. Tengo 2 `div` los cuales ocupan el 100% de la pantalla.
En el segundo `div`, el de abajo, tengo un par de botones centrados al medio, los cuales quiero ubicar hasta abajo del todo.

CSS:

```
.div2 {
  border: 1px dotted springgreen;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px dotted yellowgreen;
  height: 80%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="div1">

  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Cambia tu contraseña</a>
    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cierra la sesión</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Nótese que los bordes solo estan para verlos en la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

- Quito esta propiedad y valor:

  ```
   vertical-align: bottom;
  ```
- Luego al div con class div2 le doy las siguientes propiedades:

  ```
  .div2 {
    border: 1px dotted springgreen;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  ```
- Hago uso de flexbox para poder mover a los elementos internos `a` como cajas flexibles
- Los desplazo horizontalmente  al centro con justify-content y un valor de center y al fondo de manera vertical con `flex-end`
- Finalmente para que los botones no queden pegados uno a lado del otro, los podemos separar con esto:

  ```
  a {
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  }
  ```

Comment: Brujo! ahora, por que `vertical-align` no funciona como lo pienso, y `align-item: flex-end` si ??

Comment: @Excorpion cuando se trata de desplazar elementos prefiero usar flexbox pues me brinda mas opciones, por otro lado prácticamente casi nunca he usado vertical-align además que [según leo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) solo aplica para celdas en tablas y elementos en línea

Comment: Lo cual me hace *suponer* que si ese div no tuviera elementos en línea tales como p, otros divs, etc entonces no lograría desplazarlos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `bottom: 0px; position: absolute;` para situarlo abajo

```css
.div2 {
  border: 1px dotted springgreen;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px dotted yellowgreen;
  height: 80%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1">

  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Cambia tu contraseña</a>
    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cierra la sesión</a>
  </div>
</body>
```